# Does not display um and a textView imagemView within a relatuveLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a RelativeLayout and within it there is a textView and an imageView. In RelativeLayout has a background with an image using 9slice when I leave the tag android: background not imagemView and neither displays nor TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_cardapio_categoria_cell" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="categoria"
        android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="11dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_itens" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you attach `bg_cardapio_categoria_cell` image?

Comment: image bg_cardapio_categoria_cell.9.png, is 9slice